# How to return data using ES6 method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I was trying to return data using ES6 function , but it is returning the function instead of result.

The result should be true or false as per my code

> My Code

**get_gathereddata_status.js**

```
 export default () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const { experiment } = getState();
  const { selectedTab, gatherData } = experiment.tabs;
  const { environmentalChanges: { environmentFactor, environmentLocation } } = experiment;
  const { populationChanges: { populationlLocation, populationFactor } } = experiment;
  if (selectedTab === 'tab1') {
    return environmentFactor !== '' && environmentLocation !== '' && !gatherData[selectedTab];
  } else if (selectedTab === 'tab2') {
    return populationlLocation !== '' && populationFactor !== '' && !gatherData[selectedTab];
  }
  return false;
};
```

**mapStateToProps**

```
function mapStateToProps({ experiment }) {
  const { selectedTab } = experiment.tabs;
  const isGatherDataEnabled = gatherDataStatus();
  console.log(isGatherDataEnabled);
  return {
    selectedTab,
    isGatherDataEnabled
  };
}
```

**console.log** in the mapStateToProps

```
ƒ (dispatch, getState) {
    var _getState = getState(),
        experiment = _getState.experiment;

    var _experiment$tabs = experiment.tabs,
        selectedTab = _experiment$tabs.selectedTab,
```

Comment: `if (selectedTab === 'tab2') {
    return true;
  } else if (selectedTab === 'tab2') {
    return false;
  }` doesn't make any sense. This returns either `true` or `undefined`.

Comment: the condition is really big so that i have simplified it because of the understanding

Comment: i have updated it

Comment: Well the second `if` body will still never be executed.

Comment: Sorry bergi i have updated my code, it was my mistake

Answer (score 0):

`get_gathereddata_status.js` is returning a function that returns another function:

```
() => (dispatch, getState) => { //...}
```

So when you call it with:

```
const isGatherDataEnabled = gatherDataStatus(); 
// assuming gatherDataStatus this is the same as get_gathereddata_status.js
```

`isGatherDataEnabled` is now the function returned by `gatherDataStatus()` not the result of your second function.

I think you just want to export the second function:

```
export default (dispatch, getState) => { //.. }
```

Alternatively you could call the returned function if you really need it:

```
console.log(isGatherDataEnabled(dispatch, getState));
// You need to call this with the expected arguments. Where do these come from?
```

Comment: When i am trying this 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: getState is not a function

Comment: The second function returned by `get_gathereddata_status.js` takes two arguments: `dispatch`, `getState`. It looks like `getState` is a function. Where does that function come from? It's not shown in your example.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure we have enough information to fix everything, but this is the reason why `console.log()` is showing a function not a true/false value.